# What in-game effect does this trap in the D&D vs. Rick and Morty adventure, "The Lost Dungeon of Rickedness", have on a character?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, traps, the-lost-dungeon-of-rickedness

I was playing through the short D&D 5e adventure *The Lost Dungeon of Rickedness: Big Rick Energy* (from the *Dungeons & Dragons vs. Rick and Morty* boxed set), and encountered a particular trap:

> In [room 10](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/ddvram/the-lost-dungeon-of-rickedness#10ButtRoom) (on p. 12 of the adventure booklet), there's a trap that removes a PC's butt.

I'm wondering what in-game disadvantage (or other effect) this has on the character.

I managed to get it back; however, I don't know if a potential disadvantage to this even existed, outside of the comedic effect. I didn't get a chance to get that answer from the DM.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### There are no in-game disadvantages

Quite a bit of the content in that module is very tongue-in-cheek and references a lot of in-jokes from the show itself. The butt loss is very much in that vein and the module lists no specific mechanical disadvantages.

The module even specifically states:

> On the bright side, this doesn't inflict damage or pain. The creature just doesn't have a butt anymore. Their legs still attach to their body, albeit awkwardly and in a way that makes sitting uncomfortable. Be sure to mention this as often as possible for the rest of the adventure.

However, the feel of the module is there for you to play with - so if you're the DM you can really get creative with what this might do. If you do delve into your assless creative side, just be aware that whatever disadvantages you decide should still be fun and progress the ridiculous narrative of that dungeon.

But that doesn't mean being buttless shouldn't give advantages, either. The module goes on to state:

> ...the Order of the Buttless sees the character as a god and does whatever the character commands.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you guys. I wasn't sure and wasn't told. Thanks!!!